# R - using predict function when one variable is a binary factor

Tags: r

My linear model is trying to predict the amount gambled based on the variables sex, income, verbal, and status. Sex is a binary variable that is "Male" or "Female" (they are factors), while the rest are all numeric.

```
lm3 <- lm(gamble ~ sex + status + income + verbal, data=teengamb)
```

That is my linear model. I'm having trouble predicting the function for a male with mean status, income, and verbal:

```
newdata <- c(as.factor("Male"), mean(teengamb$status), mean(teengamb$income), mean(teengamb$verbal))
newdata <- data.frame(newdata)
predict(lm3, newdata)
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Note that the way I converted it to Male and Female is:

However, I have converted the 0=male, 1=female to "Male" and "Female."

```
teengamb$sex[teengamb$sex==0] <- "Male"
teengamb$sex[teengamb$sex==1] <- "Female"
teengamb$sex <- as.factor(teengamb$sex)
```

Comment: In what way are you having trouble? Can you show your call to `predict`?

Comment: This is what I have, and it's not working.

Comment: newdata <- c(as.factor("Male"), mean(teengamb$status), mean(teengamb$income), mean(teengamb$verbal))

newdata <- data.frame(newdata)

predict(lm3, newdata)

Comment: sorry for some reason the line spacing isnt work. but its three lines of code.

Comment: In the future, click "edit" under your question and edit it into the question (I've done it for you)

Answer (score 4):

When you create your `newdata` data frame, you have to be sure each column has a name:

```
newdata <- data.frame(sex=0, status=mean(teengamb$status),
                      income=mean(teengamb$income),
                      verbal=mean(teengamb$verbal))
predict(lm3, newdata)
# 28.24252
```

Also note that `sex` is represented as 0=male, 1=female (you can see this by doing `help(teengamb)`).

(Which means, that it should be:

```
newdata <- data.frame(sex=factor("Male", levels=c("Female", "Male")), 
                      status=mean(teengamb$status),
                      income=mean(teengamb$income),
                      verbal=mean(teengamb$verbal))
```

Comment: I edited the original post to show that i've converted the 0 to Male and the 1 to Female. When I use the code above with male/female as factors, it doesn't work (assumingly because it no longer is 0 and 1).

However, when I reread in the table so it's 0 and 1 again it works. Is there anyways the Male/Female factors can be used? Is that even the right way to write the linear model? Thanks so much!

Comment: Normally I wouldn't edit some one else's answer, but the formatting would be a mess in a comment. If 0's get changed to "Male" and 1's to "Female" then just using factor with those as levels will match up with what is in the edited question.